# Space between tabBar and searchBar of my UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have two UITableViews and both show a space of about 30 px between the tabBar and the searchBar of the tableView. 
The XIB in Interface Builder, looks good though, no space has been defined there. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set frame of both.

Comment: Well the frame size is set in IB, should that not be fine? I don't create the the tableView programmatically, I define the XIB in IB and connected it accordingly. So there is not init called in my code.

Comment: just like this yourtableview.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);//what ever size you want and same as for tabbar and searchbar so it will work according to frame size.

Comment: ok, thanks, that worked fine. However, I don't really understand, why it needs to be done in the code. It actually works too when defining the variables in IB, however, the searchBar overlaps then with the tabBar. Anyway, using the code you provided solved the issue. Thanks again.